# Ansible Roles Handlers for Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, handler

**Goal:**
I'm trying to build a role where I have handlers for Windows and Linux.

**Problem:**
Where to put the handlers?

**Idea 1:**
Put handlers in roles/handlers/main.yaml.

Issue:
If its a linux machine the windows part throws an error and vice versa:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'ansible.windows.win_shell'.
```

**Idea 2:**
Put handlers in roles/tasks/main.yaml

Issue:
It's an `include_task`, so it expects a list of tasks, not handlers.

```
ERROR! The tasks/main.yml file for role 'test_role' must contain a list of tasks
```

Background:

File structure:

```
main_playbook.yaml
roles/test_role/tasks/main.yaml
roles/test_role/handlers/main.yaml
```

If I try the second example from the [docu](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html) and put that snippet in an include task, I get following error:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: ansible.builtin.template, handlers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick N dirty pseudo code to put you on track (and by far not the only solution). For the below, to work, you need to have facts gathered on all the relevant targets.

In `handlers/main.yml`

```yaml
- name: React to something
  include_tasks: "react_to_something_{{ ansible_system }}.yml"
```

You can then create `tasks/react_to_something_Linux.yml` and `tasks/react_to_something_Win32NT.yml` which will be included by your handler depending on the remote target system.

You can debug the `ansible_system` variable on your different system to see if it correctly matches my above examples. To go further:

- you may want to explore the `ansible_distribution*` vars to see if they better suit your needs (not sure they exist on windows...)
- you can have a look at the [`first_found` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/first_found_lookup.html) which will be helpfull if you need to load in a preferred order e.g. a very specific set of tasks for a very precise distribution or a general set of tasks for an overall global system flavor or a default set of tasks in case none of the previous matched.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, will test it and "ansible_facts['os_family'] is defined and ansible_facts['os_family'] in ['Windows']" works for windows and linux distros, but it seems really hacky and not like a clean solution for this problem what I thought might be a little more common.

Comment: It's absolutely not hacky and a very common way to handle multiple OS / Distro / System in ansible roles. Just browse a bit of the most famous shared roles/collections you can find on https://ansible-galaxy.com to see for yourself. You can also have a look at the very last example in the link I gave above.

Comment: So the solution works for me, still feels wrong as the code is now super clunky to read. tasks/main.yaml ->(when linux) tasks/linux_stuff ->notify -> hander/main.yaml  -> pointing to a task back in tasks/operation_system_name_handlers.yaml. 

But thank you anyway 


(your link is not working @Zeitounator )